# PublishProcess flatMap operator does not get executed(rxjava-2)

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
/**
*  Request wrapped around flowable.
*/
public abstract class RequestFlowable<T> {

    private final PublishProcessor<String> mPublish;
    private String mName;

    public RequestFlowable(String name) {
        mName = name;
        mPublish = PublishProcessor.create();
    }

    public Flowable<T> getFlowable() {
        //return createAction();
        return mPublish.compose(new FlowableTransformer<String, T>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<T> apply(@NonNull Flowable<String> upstream) {
                return createAction();
            }
        });
      /*
       return mPublish.flatMap(new Function<String, Publisher<? extends T>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<? extends T> apply(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                return createAction();
            }
        });
       */

    }

    protected abstract Flowable<T> createAction();


    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void start() {
        mPublish.onNext("processCommand");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request: " + mName;
    }
}
```

Now for Single
  #EDIT 2

```
public abstract class Request<T> {
    private final SingleSubject<Object> mPublish;
    private String mName;

    public Request(String name) {
        mName = name;
        mPublish = SingleSubject.create();

    }

    public Single<T> getSingle() {
        return mPublish.flatMap(o -> createAction());
    }

    protected abstract Single<? extends T> createAction();


    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }


    public void start() {
        mPublish.onSuccess("Start");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Request: " + mName;
    }
}
```

The code from the above works when used with compose, like in code from above but, if instead I put the commented code - aka flatMap for some reason createAction is not executed.

## EDIT 2

The code from the above is called from another class. The corresponding code is attached below(important parts of class added):

```
 public class RequestQueue implements RequestController {
    private static final String TAG = RequestQueue.class.getSimpleName();
    private PublishSubject<Request> mRequest;
    private PublishSubject<RequestFlowable> mRequestFlowable;

    @Override
    public <T> Single<T> registerRequest(Request<T> request) {
        mRequest.onNext(request);
        return request.getSingle();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Flowable<T> registerRequestFlowable(RequestFlowable<T> request) {
        mRequestFlowable.onNext(request);
        return request.getFlowable();
    }

    public RequestQueue() {
        mRequest = PublishSubject.create();
        mRequestFlowable = PublishSubject.create();
        mRequest.subscribe(this::actionOnRequest);
        mRequestFlowable.subscribe(this::actionOnRequest);
    }

    private void actionOnRequest(Request request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "actionOnRequest() called with: request = [" + request + "]");
        request.start();
    }


    private void actionOnRequest(RequestFlowable request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "actionOnRequest() called with: request = [" + request + "]");
        request.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, `return createAction();` ignores the `upstream` and thus has no connection to the `PublishProcessor`. Second, how did you test it this setup?

Comment: This setup(with flatmap) works with Single. But I need to use with Flowable. Now, to answer your question, I have a connectFlowable call that basically has a method:    https://pastebin.com/68v0XYXd.  there is a subscriber and after on onNext start(from above) is called.

Comment: Please update the question with that code you commented.

Comment: is this clear enough or u need more stuff?. I have a feeling I am missing something essential. Because this code works fine when used with retrofit. So definitely I am missing something.

Comment: @akarnokd, regarding this: "First of all, return createAction(); ignores the upstream", this is just as a test. I use(d) compose for binding to fragment lifecycle. I noticed it works there and I wanted to see if it also works here.

Comment: `request.getFlowable()` establishes the flow but you call `mRequestFlowable.onNext(request);` before that that signals the `PublishProcessor` before anything else is connected and subscribed to it.

Comment: @akarnokd, have any idea then why it works with Singles? Because, based on ur description the same code should fail for Singles, right?. Secondly, why compose operator works?. Would be nice if you can light me on this.

Comment: @akarnokd. my first intuition was what you wrote, that it is too fast and the subscription is too late but then I saw that it works for Single and also it works for the compose operator. Then I got confused.

Comment: What `Single`s? `compose` is executed at assembly time and in your setup, the whole `getFlowable()` is practically a `return createAction();`. With the flatMap(), you need to have a subscription and after that, a call to `onNext` to trigger the function.

Comment: @akarnokd, updated the question.

Comment: @akarnokd, I understand that Single and Flowable are different, however, in theory at least, it should be possible to achieve the same thing with both, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. SingleSubject retains the single terminal event it received. Since it can only receive onSuccess and onError, it will "replay" that to late subscribers (also this is why there is no separater ReplaySingleSubject). When you call onSuccess on the SingleSubject, that value is remembered and promplty reemitted when the later subscription happens, calling your `createAction`. `PublishProcessor` also remembers its terminal events but `onNext` is not a terminal event, hence dropped without consumer.

Comment: @akarnokd, so I should use a ReplayProcessor or call onComplete, is that what you are telling me?

Comment: You could reorganize your logic, use `BehaviorProcessor` or `ReplayProcessor.createWithSize(1)`. Calling `onComplete` won't execute the flatMap function either.

Comment: @akarnokd, thank you very much for the help. Your fast help is highly appreciated(plus your work on rxjava - if you are who I think you are). Now, I have something to start from, I was going crazy over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From my comments:)

> Why does `Single` work?

`SingleSubject` retains the single terminal event it received. Since it can only receive `onSuccess` and `onError`, it will "replay" that to late subscribers (also this is why there is no separater `ReplaySingleSubject`). When you call `onSuccess` on the `SingleSubject`, that value is remembered and promplty reemitted when the later subscription happens, calling your `createAction`. `PublishProcessor` also remembers its terminal events but `onNext` is not a terminal event, hence dropped without consumer.

> How can the desired behavior be achieved via `Processor`?

You could reorganize your logic, use `BehaviorProcessor` or `ReplayProcessor.createWithSize(1)`. Calling `onComplete` won't execute the `flatMap` function either.

Comment: tested and it works very well with ReplaySubject and also with BehaviorSubject. I re-read again the Subjects as it seems I "missed" this very sensitive info about PublishSubject. Thanks again.